# WordPress Current Page Item With Anchored Tags

Tags: html, css, wordpress

First visit http://velnikolic.com/music/?page_id=6#test

Then hover over the music tab on the navigation. There is a highlight on both "Classic and Category 2". I think the reason for this is because they both link to anchor tags on the Music page. Is there a way to highlight only the item clicked on. For example if I clicked "Classic" only Classic and Music would be highlighted not all three.

Answer (score 1):

one Idea is that u can remove ".current-menu-item" on the rest submenu items,

and only make sure you assign ".current-menu-item" to the one u cliked

when u click on one of the submenu "li".

[image: problem menu incorrectly assigned current class]

[image: the right class]